# using servlet-api 3 bundle in adobe CQ5

Tags: osgi, aem

I'm trying to use the servlet-api version 3 in an Adobe CQ5 installation, without much success.

there is already a bundle that exports the javax.servlet package (version 2.5), so I deployed a bundle with version 3.1.0. this bundle starts ok.

The problem is starting the bundle that uses the api v3. I am getting an OSGi exception that I cannot fully understand:

> POST /system/console/bundles/250 HTTP/1.1] cqse-httpservice %bundles.pluginTitle: Cannot start  (org.osgi.framework.BundleException:
>
> Constraint violation for package 'javax.servlet' when resolving module 250.9 between existing import 266.0.javax.servlet
>
> BLAMED ON [[250.9] package; (&(package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.0.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]
>
> and uses constraint 22.1.javax.servlet
>
> BLAMED ON [[250.9] package; (package=com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms), [210.0] package;
>    (&(package=org.apache.sling.api.resource)(version>=2.0.0)), [93.0]
>    package; (&(package=javax.servlet)(version>=2.4.0))])

- bundle 266 exports javax.servlet v=3.10 (I installed this one)
- bundle 22 exports javax.servlet v=2.5 (provided by CQ5)
- bundle 250 (mine) imports javax.servlet,version=[3.0,4) from 266. It also imports packages from 210 and 93.
- bundle 210 imports javax.servelt v=2.5 from 22 (but the import in manifest does not have a version. maybe this is the problem?)
- bundle 93 has javax.servlet; version="2.4" in the Import-package. but it resolved to javax.servlet,version=2.5.0 from  (22) somehow.

The problem seems to be around the dependencies of bundle 250, but Im not sure what is the problem. AFAIK two versions of a package can coexist in an OSGi container. bundles 210 and 93 are running without issues.

Comment: This article lays out in depth what a usage constraint violation is and why it can be difficult to track down. http://njbartlett.name/2011/02/09/uses-constraints.html Hopefully that helps you track down your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the  [article](http://njbartlett.name/2011/09/02/uses-constraints.html) left in the comments, I noticed that dependencies of my bundle expose classes of the servlet api 2.5. This is causing the constraint and prevents my bundle. If I understand correctly the classpath from bundle 210 is expanded up to my bundle.

So, the only option will be to remove the dependency of my bundle with the other bundles, which I am afraid I cannot do. I will have to deal without the V3 api

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the fact that the used http-service only supports servlet 2.5 that's why this is the pre-installed servlet version. Since you installed a servlet 3.0 api your bundle does resolve but as it tries to export a service which is picked up by the http-service you run into this issue. The root cause is the http-service implementation that is used. I don't know if this would work but you might try to replace the http service version by   using Pax-Web 2 or 3 instead. Pax-Web does support Servlet API since version 2.

Comment: I'm afraid the problem lies in what @Moch Daear commented. Some classes of the http servlet are exposed by the api of the bundles, so their dependencies require version 2.5.